# Bootstrap-table data clears on search, filter or paginate after Ajax call

Tags: django, ajax, bootstrap-table

In my Django template I have a bootstrap-table (version 1.21.2) (https://bootstrap-table.com/) which is filled with multiple customers, whenever a customer is clicked, it will create a popup with a bootstrap-table in which all data for that customer is displayed using Ajax.

The problem, is that, whenever I try to search, filter or paginate, it clears the entire table. I think this is because bootstrap-table clears the entire table, and then refills it with whatever you're trying to search.

Here is my code:

Ajax:

```
function get_customer_leadtime(customerCode, customerName, warehouse) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "{% url 'get_customer_leadtime' %}",
                data:{
                    "customerCode": customerCode,
                    "customerName": customerName,
                    "warehouse": warehouse
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var title =  customerName
                    var table = $("#customerLeadtimeTable tbody");
                    document.getElementById("customerLeadtimeLabel").innerHTML = title;
                    table.empty()
                    $.each(response, function(idx, customerInfo){
                        $.each(customerInfo, function(_, details){
                            table.append(
                                "<tr><td>"+details.Article
                                +"</td><td>"+details.Leadtime
                                +"</td></tr>"
                            );
                        });
                    });

                    $("#customerLeadtimeModal").modal('show');
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        }
```

Ajax GET example URL: GET /get/ajax/leadtime?customerCode=00000&customerName=SomeCustomer%20BV&warehouse=SomeLocation HTTP/1.1" 200 9216

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm"
    id="customerLeadtimeTable" 
    data-toggle="table"
    data-show-multi-sort="true"
    data-show-search-clear-button="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-search="true"
    data-filter-control-multiple-search="true"
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-search-align="left"
    data-pagination="true" 
    data-side-pagination="client" 
    data-page-size="10" 
    data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, ALL]"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col" data-field="Article" data-width="50" data-width-unit="%">Article</th>
       <th scope="col" data-field="Leadtime" data-width="50" data-width-unit="%">Average leadtime</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Image of the table before searching:
[image: initial table]

Image of the table after searching:
[image: table after search]

At first it was fine just using plain data without a filter or search option, but after a while there were too many rows, and to search for something would be like a needle in a haystack.

I've tried some of the options displayed here: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/
But my efforts were in vain, since none of them seem to work. (or maybe i implemented them wrong)